# Populate unordered list in PHP

Tags: php, list, for-loop, foreach, unordered

I need to build something like this menu (unordered list) above, I have 2 associative PHP arrays, what is the best way to do it?:

```
<ul>
  <li>Administración
     <ul>
       <li>Gestor Usuarios
         <ul>
           <li>Acceder</li>
           <li>Crear usuario</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Roles y permisos</li>
       <li>Apariencia</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Configuración</li>
  <li>Gestión Scripts</li>
  <li>Gestión de Escenarios</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>    

$subpaginas = [
                    1 => [
                          1 => 'Gestión de Usuarios',
                          2 => 'Roles y permisos',
                          3 => 'Apariencia'
                        ],
                    2 => [],
                    3 => [],
                    4 => [],
                    5 => [],
                    6 => [],
                    7 => [],
                    8 => []
                  ];

$paginas = [
              1 => 'Administración',
              2 => 'Configuración',
              3 => 'Gestión de Scripts',
              4 => 'Gestión de Escenarios',
              5 => 'Planificador',
              6 => 'Monitorización',
              7 => 'Resultado Ejecuciones',
              8 => 'Dashboard'
            ];
```

PD: $paginas array is in relation with $subpaginas array.
Thanks.

Comment: Judging from the information given, any overhead from either of the chosen methods is negligible. Choose whatever you feel most comfortable with

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will work:

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach($paginas as $key => $menu): ?>
    <li>
      <?php echo $menu; ?>
      <?php if(!empty($subpaginas[$key])): ?>
        <ul>
          <?php foreach($subpaginas[$key] as $submenu): ?>
            <li><?php echo $submenu; ?></li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```